# Report Builder 3.0 freezes up when opening up query designer

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

I've been searching for days and I can't find anything that fixes this issue. When I open report builder 3.0, I'm able to see and open reports. I can open up the report. I can view dataset properties. When I click on query, it hangs. If the query in the particular report is text only, I can open it. If the query was made with the gui of query designer, it freezes and eventually fails.

The dataset is embedded in the report.

If I create a new report I'm able to open query designer only in that report. It seems to only effect reports that have been created prior to this week.

Testing I've performed:

- Different user profile
- Different user
- Different user profile on different computer
- Different user on different computer
- Installing sql server 2008 r2 SP2
- Uninstalling and reinstalling report builder
  3.0

SSRS Logs show this in reference to the report I'm opening.

```
library!ReportServer_0-2!1328!01/15/2014-12:24:15:: Call to GetSystemPropertiesAction().
library!ReportServer_0-2!11fc!01/15/2014-12:24:15:: Call to ListChildrenAction(/, False).
library!ReportServer_0-2!1328!01/15/2014-12:24:18:: Call to ListChildrenAction(/CustomReports, False).
library!ReportServer_0-2!11fc!01/15/2014-12:24:19:: Call to ListChildrenAction(/CustomReports/Missing Weeks Reports, False).
library!ReportServer_0-2!1328!01/15/2014-12:24:21:: Call to GetItemTypeAction(/CustomReports/Missing Weeks Reports/MW_Royalties_RBC).
library!ReportServer_0-2!11fc!01/15/2014-12:24:21:: Call to GetItemTypeAction(/CustomReports/Missing Weeks Reports/MW_Royalties_RBC).
library!ReportServer_0-2!11fc!01/15/2014-12:24:21:: Call to GetReportDefinitionAction(/CustomReports/Missing Weeks Reports/MW_Royalties_RBC).
library!ReportServer_0-2!1328!01/15/2014-12:24:22:: Call to GetItemDataSourcesAction(/CustomReports/Missing Weeks Reports/MW_Royalties_RBC).
library!ReportServer_0-2!11fc!01/15/2014-12:24:22:: Call to GetItemTypeAction(/CustomReports/Missing Weeks Reports/MW_Royalties_RBC).
library!ReportServer_0-2!11fc!01/15/2014-12:24:22:: Call to GetReportItemReferencesAction(/CustomReports/Missing Weeks Reports/MW_Royalties_RBC).
library!ReportServer_0-2!1328!01/15/2014-12:24:23:: Call to GetItemTypeAction(/CustomReports/Missing Weeks Reports/MW_Royalties_RBC).
library!ReportServer_0-2!1328!01/15/2014-12:24:23:: Call to GetReportParametersAction(/CustomReports/Missing Weeks Reports/MW_Royalties_RBC).
library!ReportServer_0-2!11fc!01/15/2014-12:24:23:: Call to GetPropertiesAction(/CustomReports/Missing Weeks Reports/MW_Royalties_RBC, PathBased).
library!ReportServer_0-2!1328!01/15/2014-12:24:23:: Call to CreateReportEditSessionAction(Parent=/CustomReports/Missing Weeks Reports, Report=MW_Royalties_RBC).
library!ReportServer_0-2!11fc!01/15/2014-12:24:27:: Call to GetItemTypeAction(/Shared Data Sources/Company 001).
library!ReportServer_0-2!1328!01/15/2014-12:24:27:: Call to GetDataSourceContentsAction(/Shared Data Sources/Company 001).
library!WindowsService_0!7cc!01/15/2014-12:28:56:: i INFO: Call to CleanBatch()
library!WindowsService_0!7cc!01/15/2014-12:28:56:: i INFO: Cleaned 0 batch records, 0 policies, 4 sessions, 0 cache entries, 2 snapshots, 12 chunks, 0 running jobs, 0 persisted streams, 25 segments, 25 segment mappings, 0 edit sessions.
library!WindowsService_0!7cc!01/15/2014-12:28:56:: i INFO: Call to CleanBatch() ends
library!ReportServer_0-2!1328!01/15/2014-12:34:37:: Call to GetSystemPropertiesAction().
library!ReportServer_0-2!1130!01/15/2014-12:34:37:: Call to ListChildrenAction(/, False).
library!ReportServer_0-2!1328!01/15/2014-12:34:39:: Call to ListChildrenAction(/CustomReports, False).
library!ReportServer_0-2!1130!01/15/2014-12:34:41:: Call to ListChildrenAction(/CustomReports/Submitted Weeks Reports, False).
library!ReportServer_0-2!1328!01/15/2014-12:34:43:: Call to ListChildrenAction(/CustomReports/Submitted Weeks Reports/Discard, False).
library!ReportServer_0-2!13f4!01/15/2014-12:34:45:: Call to ListChildrenAction(/CustomReports/Submitted Weeks Reports, False).
library!ReportServer_0-2!1130!01/15/2014-12:34:46:: Call to ListChildrenAction(/CustomReports, False).
library!ReportServer_0-2!13f4!01/15/2014-12:34:48:: Call to ListChildrenAction(/CustomReports/Missing Weeks Reports, False).
library!ReportServer_0-2!1130!01/15/2014-12:34:50:: Call to GetItemTypeAction(/CustomReports/Missing Weeks Reports/MW_Royalties_RBC).
library!ReportServer_0-2!13f4!01/15/2014-12:34:50:: Call to GetItemTypeAction(/CustomReports/Missing Weeks Reports/MW_Royalties_RBC).
library!ReportServer_0-2!13f4!01/15/2014-12:34:50:: Call to GetReportDefinitionAction(/CustomReports/Missing Weeks Reports/MW_Royalties_RBC).
library!ReportServer_0-2!1130!01/15/2014-12:34:51:: Call to GetItemDataSourcesAction(/CustomReports/Missing Weeks Reports/MW_Royalties_RBC).
library!ReportServer_0-2!13f4!01/15/2014-12:34:51:: Call to GetItemTypeAction(/CustomReports/Missing Weeks Reports/MW_Royalties_RBC).
library!ReportServer_0-2!13f4!01/15/2014-12:34:51:: Call to GetReportItemReferencesAction(/CustomReports/Missing Weeks Reports/MW_Royalties_RBC).
library!ReportServer_0-2!1130!01/15/2014-12:34:51:: Call to GetItemTypeAction(/CustomReports/Missing Weeks Reports/MW_Royalties_RBC).
library!ReportServer_0-2!1130!01/15/2014-12:34:51:: Call to GetReportParametersAction(/CustomReports/Missing Weeks Reports/MW_Royalties_RBC).
library!ReportServer_0-2!13f4!01/15/2014-12:34:52:: Call to GetPropertiesAction(/CustomReports/Missing Weeks Reports/MW_Royalties_RBC, PathBased).
library!ReportServer_0-2!1130!01/15/2014-12:34:52:: Call to CreateReportEditSessionAction(Parent=/CustomReports/Missing Weeks Reports, Report=MW_Royalties_RBC).
```

Comment: Might try opening up your report's XML markup and looking for broken tags etc.

Comment: I'm not finding any broken tags. There's no reason these reports should have changed at all, since they have not been edited for months.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue by recreating the data sources and queries. This is quite time consuming but has been the only resolution to this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I personally had that issue multiple times and it was overwhelmingly caused by just two reasons:

1. You're trying to edit a report created using different version of the Report Builder. Unfortunately there's no substantial backward compatibility in RB, so only solution in that case is to recreate the DataSource and DataSet from scratch.
2. Source for the DataSet is missing a column - i.e. there's a column `[Name]` in the Dataset definition, but table that's the source doesn't have it.

There are sometimes other reasons, but I was unable to verify them. However, the list above I was able to confirm.

Comment: My similar issue was getting parameter error 'the query contains the parameter which is not declared' but the kicker is the error was pertaining to the query designer version.  Married up the querys to be the same, fixed the associated parameters then back in business.    The query designer is literally bug and needs to be removed.  Build querys externally then add to query properties and build manually within report builder for full control.

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar issue where if right-clicking the dataset and clicking "Query", Report Builder would freeze, but the workaround was simpler: click "Dataset Properties" instead of "Query" and then you can click the "Query Designer" button (or directly edit in the "Query" box if preferred).

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me:

1. I created a stored procedure using the query I put on the Query Designer.
2. I used the stored procedure option to call the previously created stored procedure instead of using the Query Designer.